# Lucene BooleanQuery with [ (OR) AND (OR) AND (OR) ]

Tags: java, lucene

I have three different list of terms which I am passing to termQuery using BooleanQuery. I am getting the result but not sure if this is the right way to use the BooleanQuery. Any suggestion on improving the search result will be great help.

```
BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
BooleanQuery treeQuery = new BooleanQuery();
BooleanQuery fruitQuery = new BooleanQuery();
BooleanQuery areaQuery = new BooleanQuery();        
String[] trees = {"Drago Milenario", "Sunland Baobab", "Fig tree", "The Cotton Tree", "olive",...........}; 
String[] fruitsTrees = {"Mango", "Apple", "Almond", "Bael", "Durian",........}; 
String[] localityLst = {"Asia", "Europe", "North America", "Other"}; 

List<String> treeLst = Arrays.asList(words);  
List<String> fruitsLst = Arrays.asList(words);  
List<String> areaLst = Arrays.asList(words);  
for (String tree : treeLst) {
    treeQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", "\"" + tree + "\"")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
for (String fruitTree : fruitsLst) {
    fruitQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", "\"" + fruitTree + "\"")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
for (String areatype : areaLst) { 
    areaQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", "\"" + areatype + "\"")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}

finalQuery.add(treeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
finalQuery.add(fruitQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
finalQuery.add(areaQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

if (finalQuery.toString().trim().length() == 0)
    return new ArrayList<String>();
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_4_9, "", stadAnalyzer);
Query query = qp.parse(finalQuery.toString())
```

This is what I am expecting finalQuery String

```
( (content :"Drago Milenario" OR content :"Sunland Baobab" OR content:"Fig tree" OR ...) 
AND
  (content :"Mango" OR content :"Apple" OR ...) 
AND
(content :"Asia" OR content :"North America") )
```

Comment: what's the problem with this approach? you didn't mention it.

Comment: Just wanted to check if there are any better way to do the same thing

Comment: To me, this approach is ok.